# UTF8 Encoding in iOS / swift for email containing +

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

How to encode URL parameters with UTF8 encoding in Query string format URL/param1/param2/param3

I have even tried URLHostAllowedCharacterSet, which encodes special characters but not '+' character.

How to encode email containing + character using almofire request?

Comment: have you tried it, have your own attempt? Your code would clear the question.

Comment: Yes I have tried to pass email i.e a+b@gmail.com as param1, but server takes + as a white space. I want to send this email with encoding so server can accept + character.

Comment: And have you tried to escape the character with '\' before the '+'?

Comment: how to add escape sequence when + sign occurs dynamically?

Comment: Using the function that cares about escaping the whole string you expect to contain the char. Unless you add your code, it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add an extension to handle the encoding and then just call the extension when you want to encode.

```
extension String {
    func stringByAddingPercentEncodingForRFC3986() -> String? {
        let unreserved = "-._~/?:"
        let allowed = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()
        allowed.addCharactersInString(unreserved)
        return stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowed)
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
let query = "http://test.com/param1& param2+ param3"
let encoded = query.stringByAddingPercentEncodingForRFC3986()!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
  func stringByAddingPercentEncodingForRFC3986() -> String? {
    let unreserved = "-._~/?:"
    let allowedCharacterSet = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumeric()
    allowedCharacterSet.addCharacters(in: unreserved)
    return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet as CharacterSet)
  }
}

let encodedVal = usernameTextField.text.stringByAddingPercentEncodingForRFC3986()
```

--------- OR ----------

```
extension String {
   var urlEncoded: String? {
    let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet.alphanumerics.union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-._~/?:"))
    return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet)
  }
}

let encodedVal = usernameTextField.text.urlEncoded
```